# Galois group of $x^{2^k}+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

What is the Galois group of $f(x)=x^{2^k}+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: why down vote? I think that this is a perfectly valid question and this is not homework problem!

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Where did you encounter the problem?

Comment: @user186881: I haven't downvoted, but I think that it is better to give some context for a question and to share your own ideas.

Comment: For example, have you figured out what happens when $k=1$ and $k=2$? Warning: false leads there! Also, what do you know about the Galois groups of [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)?

Answer (score 1):

The splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q (\zeta_{2^{k+1}})$, where $\zeta_{2^{k+1}}$ is the $2^{k+1}$-th primitive root of unit. When $k=0$ we have that $\zeta_{2}=-1$, so $\mathbb Q (-1)=\mathbb Q$ and $Gal(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Q)=\{e\}$.When $k\geq 1$ it's known that $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2^{k+1}})/\mathbb Q) \cong (\mathbb Z_{2^{k+1}})^*\cong \mathbb Z_{2^{k-1}} \times \mathbb Z_2$.